# symfony2 get paramConverter value in custom annotation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm trying to create my own symfony2 annotations.
What I'm trying to achieve is get the paramConverter object in my annotation (in my controller), like

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("member", class="AppBundle:Member")
 * @Route("my/route/{member}", name="my_route")
 * @MyCustomAnnotation("member", some_other_stuff="...")
 */
public function myAction(Member $member) {...}
```

The purpose here is to get the "member" in my annotation, so I can work on it before it is passed to the controller action

Currently, my annotation "reader" is working as a service

```
MyCustomAnnotationDriver:
            class: Vendor\Bundle\Driver\CustomAnnotationDriver
            tags: [{name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController}]
            arguments: [@annotation_reader]
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it few months ago but I choose much simpler approach. My use-case was to inject object based on currently logged user (either `Profile` or `Teacher`).

Check this GIST out:

GIST: https://gist.github.com/24d3b1778bc86429c7b3.git

PASTEBIN (gist currently doesn't work): http://pastebin.com/CBjrHvbM

Then, register the converter as:

```
<service id="my_param_converter" class="AcmeBundle\Services\RoleParamConverter">
    <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/>
    <tag name="request.param_converter" converter="role_converter"/>
</service>
```

Finally, use it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/news")
 * @ParamConverter("profile", class="AcmeBundle:Profile", converter="role_converter")
 */
public function indexAction(Profile $profile){
    // action's body
}
```

You can also, apply this custom `ParamConverter` to controller's class.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Nice workaround, not exactly what I need because it's for security concerns tho.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to implement additional security measures to ensure validity of injected data. `Request` object does not leave your server so there is no fear that some data might get leaked due to non-SSL connection...

Comment: Scratch that, I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution lurking in the doc. In fact, the event is working with the Request, so for every params in my route, I check the corresponding ParamConverter, and get the entity.

Here is what I get :

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
        if (!is_array($controller = $event->getController()))
            return; //Annotation only available in controllers

        $object      = new \ReflectionObject($controller[0]);
        $method      = $object->getMethod($controller[1]);
        $annotations = new ArrayCollection();
        $params      = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($this->reader->getMethodAnnotations($method) as $configuration) {

            if($configuration instanceof SecureResource) //SecureResource is my annotation
                $annotations->add($configuration);
            else if($configuration instanceof \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter)
                $params->add($configuration);
        }

        foreach($annotations as $ann) {

            $name = $ann->resource; // member in my case

            $param = $params->filter(

                function($entry) use ($name){
                    if($entry->getName() == $name) return $entry;
                } //Get the corresponding paramConverter to get the repo

            )[0];

            $entityId = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route_params')[$name];
            $entity   = $this->em->getRepository($param->getClass())->find($entityId);

            //.. do stuff with your entity

        }
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've also done something like that (actually on the same project as one from the answer) ;)